# Pandas to_excel not writing dataframe, only columns/index

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I thought the point of the `to_excel` method was to write a given dataframe to excel. However, if I used the following code:

```
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(PATH, workbookName + ".xlsx"), 
                            engine='xlsxwriter')

workbook = writer.book # Only needed for formatting

dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheetName, index=True)

workbook.close()
```

it only writes the column headers and the index, not any values (cells are blank). I've tried using `writer.save()` too, but it doesn't help. The only way to get it to write the cells is to literally call `workbook.write()` for every single cell.

In every example I've seen, `to_excel` should be sufficient. What's going wrong?

Comment: What are the contents of the 'dataframe' variable? (Also, I recommend that you rename that variable to something more specific if you can)

Comment: What is `sheetName`? What if you leave that out of the call to `to_excel`? And would it be enough just to run `dataframe.to_excel(os.path.join(PATH, workbookName + '.xlsx')` without any of these explicit steps?

Comment: sheetName is the name of the sheet it's writing to. It's not necessary (I think) if the workbook only has one sheet, but if it has multiple, then it's needed.